# Calculus cardboard box problem

Tags: calculus, maximum-principle

I have a question regarding a rectangular box. The question is:

> What are the dimensions of a rectangular box of greatest volume that can be constructed from 400 square inches of cardboard if the base is a square?Assume that the box has no top.

I know that that volume is length times height and width. But I am not sure how to set up a formula to solve the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say the base is an $x \times x$ square, and call height $y$.

Since you know volume is length $\times$ width $\times$ height, we have that

$yx^2 = V\tag{1}$

You also know that you have $400$ square inches to work with.

The surface area of the box is $x^2$ (the area of the bottom of the box - no top since its to be an open box), plus $4\times x\times y$, the area of the 4 sides of the box.

So, $x^2 + 4xy = 400\tag{2}$

Now, we can use equatins $(1), (2)$ to put together a formula for maximizing Volume:

From $(2)$: $4xy = 400 - x^2 \iff y = \dfrac{400 - x^2}{4x}\tag{3}$

Substituting for $y$ from equation $(3)$ into equation $(1)$ gives us:

$$V = x^2y = x^2\left(\dfrac{400 - x^2}{4x}\right)$$
$$ \iff V = \frac{x(400-x^2)}{4} = \frac 14 x(400 - x^2) = 100x - \frac 14 x^3\tag{4}$$

Now, to maximize V, in terms of x, we differentiate $V$, set $V' = 0$, and determine critical points to test for maximums.

In your derivative, you'll find you get a difference of squares, which factors fairly nicely, revealing the possible roots for $x$: one positive, one negative. So your maximum is going to have to occur when $x = $ positive root.

Once you've found $x_{\text{max}}$, use this to solve for $y$ (height), using equation $(3)$, and once you have $y$, you're ready to compute the maximum possible volume of the box (given the constraint of the total available cardboard) using equation $(1)$ and substituting into that equation the values you obtain for $x_{\text{max}}$ and $y$ to solve for V = volume, in cubic inches.

Comment: thanks I will try and find the maximums. One thing is that in the question we assume that the box has no top so I would not use the surface area?

Comment: Yes it makes sense as you set $y=v/x^2$

Comment: I fixed that, and it didn't affect the equations I set up. We don't know volume until we find $y$. So use the equation $2$ (it correctly represents an open box's surface area) to find y, when you know the $x$ value for maximum volume. Then when you know x, y, you, you plug them in $x^y = V$

Comment: yes I have a critical point at x= square root(400/3) I have to do a first derivative test now.

Comment: You should get a critical point at $\dfrac{20}{\sqrt 3} = \sqrt{\dfrac{400}{3}}$, which is what you've got!. Now use equation (3) to compute y, using your value for $x$.

Comment: For y I have gotten 2/5

Comment: y is the height and x would be lenght times times width right

Comment: no, x would be length or width, $x^2 = $ length times width, so you want to compute $V = x^2y$

Comment: Yes y is height: And for y I got $y = \dfrac{400 - 400/3}{4\sqrt{400/3}} = \dfrac{10\sqrt 3}{3}$

Comment: Are you there, Fernando?

Comment: yes I think I understand the final dimensions are x=square root (400/3) and y is 10 square root(3)/3

Comment: You got it, now all that's left is to compute $V = x^2y$! Oh, actually you're done, you need only the dimensions, which are correct!

Comment: thanks for the help on this and other problems as well

Comment: Yes, correct. x = width, x = length, and y = height. Good job!

Answer (score 1):

**Steps**

1. Formulate the question mathematically: out of all the possible square-base, open-top boxes with surface area $400\,\text{in}^2$, we want to find the one with the greatest volume.
2. Note that calculus provides a technique for finding the maximum of a function: we know that anywhere a (differentiable) function attains a maximum, its derivative must be zero there.
3. Construct the formulas for the surface area and volume of a square-base, open-top box whose base has side length $b$ and whose height is $h$.
4. Use the constraint that the surface area must equal $400\,\text{in}^2$ to express one of the variables in the surface area formula in terms of the other. Thus, each square-base, open-top box of surface area $400\,\text{in}^2$ is determined entirely by the value of first variable.
5. Express the volume a of a square-base, open-top box of surface area $400\,\text{in}^2$ as a function of this one variable, take its derivative, and find where the derivative is 0. Then check by hand which of these point(s) are the maximum.

Comment: Point #1 does not correspond to the question as currently worded...

Comment: Oops :) That's what I get for reformulating one of my answers to another question. Corrected now.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: This problem is equivalent to maximizing $ V(x,y) = x^2y  $ given the constraint $x^2 + 4xy = 400$ (Note that the question specifies that box is open.) You can follow a similar procedure to amwhy's post now to solve the question.